# Debugging Django from the command-line

Tags: django, debugging

I'm working on debugging Django from the command-line.  I'm working with `django_extensions`, and I have [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) installed and ideally I'd like to be able to extract as much information in the shell as possible.  How would I go about this task most efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by Geo `manage.py shell` is good but since you have `django_extensions` already installed then Carl's suggestion of `manage.py shell_plus` is even better... saves a ton of typing.

But, as a third suggestion that is a bit less general, you might also want to check out [django-viewtools](http://eric.themoritzfamily.com/2009/02/17/announcing-django-viewtools/).  I personally tend to use shell_plus, but this might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the viewtools link... I'll be checking it out very soon. Best answer, especially since you read my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have django_extensions installed, use

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

to get all of your model classes automatically pre-loaded.

Comment: Shell_plus is great.  Also be sure to checkout iPython which adds a lot of useful features when using the shell (like printing dictionaries in 'pretty' tabbed and readable way instead of a clobber of data) -- http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
python manage.py shell
```

More info [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Yes, knew about that from the docs. I'd probably go with shell_plus, since I'm already using django extensions.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite ways of debuging django problems is using the `./manage runserver_plus` command to the `django_extensions`. It uses the `Werkzeug` debuger, which gives you a python shell in the web browser itself. If you want a shell anywhere in the code, just type some bogus python, like a simple `a`, and you will get a shell when that code is executed.

Another nice tool is `ipdb` *ipython debugger*. Its the same as pdb but better (and uses ipython. With this, and runserver_plus, you can insert `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`, and you will get a ipython shell with an debugger in the same window as you have runserver_plus.
Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands for a list of commands you can use inside the debugger.